# Check data match user type or not

Tags: json, vue.js

I want to ask if I use session storage to store the user type, and now I want the user can only see the report that they belong to, how should I do that? Also, when I print out the userType, there are [ and ", how can I remove them?

Listing.vue

```
<template>
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Format</th>
                <th scope="col">User Type</th>
            </tr>
            
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr v-for="report in reports" :key="report">
                <td scope="row">{{ report.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ report.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ report.format }}</td>
                <td>{{ report.userType }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
<template/>
<script>
export default {
    
    data(){
        return{
            reports: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3002/reports')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.reports = data)
            .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
    },
}
</script>
```

db.json

```
{
    "reports": [
        { "id": "HOMES-USER-LOGIN", "format": "HTML", "name": "Both can access", "userType":["HAuser", "Supplier"]},
        { "id": "HOMES-BUD-R702-1", "format": "PDF", "name": "Only HAuser can access1" , "userType":["HAuser"]},
        { "id": "HOMES-CON-R701", "format": "XLS", "name": "Only HAuser can access2" , "userType":["HAuser"]},
        { "id": "HOMES-GRB-R002-1", "format": "PDF", "name": "Only supplier can access1" , "userType":["Supplier"]},
        { "id": "HOMES-PAY-R701", "format": "PDF", "name": "Only supplier can access2" , "userType":["Supplier"]}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to remove characters from userType, you should do it in the backend. Can you show part of your code where you send reports? First of all, you should remove the array, which I show you in your example.

Logic example for send data from localstorage:

```
mounted() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3002/reports', this.getAuthUser)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.reports = data)
            .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
},
computed: {
   getAuthUser() {
      return window.localStorage.getItem('user');
   }
}
```

Comment: Those reports are hardcode in db.json